Who are the leading academics writing about commercial real estate?
I’m looking to learn more about the interaction between economics, financial stability and commercial real estate and was wondering which academics are considered leading experts in this area. I’m aware of Stijn Van Nieuwerburgh as one prominent name, but are there others whose work on CRE is particularly influential or widely cited?

The Handbook of Regional and Urban Economics should give some names to start. There's also the Handbook of Real Estate and Macroeconomics.
